# How to store data files on DropBox

Tags: r, shiny, dropbox, shinydashboard

I am trying to save the uploaded files (within my shiny app) to a remote dropBox. I have been trying to implement what I learned here: [https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html ](Permanent Storage) but so far no luck. 
What I need is to save and store these data files in a dropBox, and then (when needed) to show the datasets on the dashboard.
It looks a tricky task (at least for me, as I am new to shiny). Any support is very welcome!

Here it's a snippet of my code (on server):

```
#### To upload file and generate a Table ####
data <- reactive({
  req(input$file)

  ext <- tools::file_ext(input$file$name)
  switch(ext,
         csv = vroom::vroom(input$file$datapath, delim = ","),
         tsv = vroom::vroom(input$file$datapath, delim = "\t"),
         xlsx = read_excel(input$file$datapath, sheet = 1),
         validate("Invalid file; Please upload a .csv, .tsv or excel file")
  )
})

#  When the Upload a File button is clicked, save the data
 observeEvent(input$file, {
  saveData(data())
})

# Show the table results on dashboard
output$table <- renderDataTable({
  input$file
  data()
  # DropBox
  loadData()
```

})

The functions loadData() and saveData() (they were taken from the link above) are defined before the ui and server pieces.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61904147/11437205

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I found a solution.